# Is there a way to split audio?

Tags: audio, speakers, stereo, multichannel

I have two separate mono speakers. Is there a way to split the output from my computer into two 3.5mm jacks, one being the left channel and the other being the right? Also, I have a SoundBlasterX AE5, is there some hacks way to do what I want without buying another external piece of hardware (if there is a piece of hardware to do it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep! All you need is one of [these cables.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000068O5H)